# Форма заполнения HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Всем привет, подскажите, как сделать такую форму?
Заранее спасибо[image]

Comment: "Through hard thinking." `border-radius`, `opacity`.

Comment: Я не на столько тупой, я говорил про поля и кнопку отправки..

Comment: Вы говорили? Где?

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев А что поля ? Они даже не оформлены, placeholder прописываете и всё. Кнопку на css сделать не выйдет, не целиком, по крайней мере, нужна будет картинка с дыркой в виде галочки, лучше вектор (svg) в остальном ничего сложного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 330px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
}

.map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  padding: 35px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
}

.form__field {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.form__field--textarea {
  height: 60px;
}

.form__submit {
  max-height: 40px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.form__submit>svg {
  max-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="map"></div>
  <form class="form">
    <input type="text" class="form__field" placeholder="Name" required>
    <input type="email" class="form__field" placeholder="Email" required>
    <textarea placeholder="Message" class="form__field form__field--textarea" required></textarea>
    <button class="form__submit"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 426.667 426.667" style="enable-background:new 0 0 426.667 426.667;" xml:space="preserve">
<path style="fill:#6AC259;" d="M213.333,0C95.518,0,0,95.514,0,213.333s95.518,213.333,213.333,213.333
 c117.828,0,213.333-95.514,213.333-213.333S331.157,0,213.333,0z M174.199,322.918l-93.935-93.931l31.309-31.309l62.626,62.622
 l140.894-140.898l31.309,31.309L174.199,322.918z"/>
<g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g><g></g>
<g></g><g></g>
</svg></button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное